# PHP find out where die was used

Tags: php, debugging, die

I've got some quite complicated php website and after some changes I'm getting *'white screen of death'*, I'm pretty sure its some `die;` exectued somewhere.

Is there any way to show file and line of code where `die;` was executed?

[edit]

To response answers here - it's not about finding all `die`s in entire project. It's about showing witch one was used during some specific execution. It's becouse sometimes (usually with frameworks like mvc) it's not so easy to know what php files were used.

Comment: CTRL + F in most text editors. I use Sublime Text, CTRL + SHIFT + F searches in entire directories. What operating system are you using? This could also be a simple command if you use Linux OS.

Comment: Check log files first and make sure it is die() or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE supports text search as others already pointed out. As an alternative, use grep. A command like `grep -rnwI die *` in the root of your source folder would help you along a bit.

Also, if you haven't done so already, enable `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. That way you won't have to guess whether a `die();` or `exit;` is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your project in any IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse and then you can use the FIND feature inside it .

Simply search for "die" then IDE will let you know all the files having words "die" along with their line numbers.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

**use some of the tools like netbeans press ctrl+F to search the value in your project**